# Where can I find XP drivers for a Dell Vostro 1015?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

I changed my OS from Vista to XP but I can't find functional graphics drivers.

The machine in question is a **Dell Vostro 1015**. Do you have any idea where I can find it?

Answer (score 1):

Try the installation package [here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=19412&keyword=x4500&lang=eng). The graphics processor in that machine is part of the Mobile Intel 4 Series Express Chipset Family

Answer (score 1):

Dell Support recommends the [Intel GM45 Express Chipset Family](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&releaseid=R225247&SystemID=VOS_N_1015&servicetag=&os=WW1&osl=en&deviceid=18283&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=2&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=27&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=322608).

You can find all the drivers in Dell's [Drivers & Downloads for Vostro Notebook 1015](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?os=WW1&catid=-1&dateid=-1&impid=-1&osl=EN&typeid=-1&formatid=-1&servicetag=&SystemID=VOS_N_1015&hidos=WLH&hidlang=en&TabIndex=&scanSupported=False&scanConsent=False).

Comment: +1 it's the right place to find what is suitable for your laptop.